# How to search in a Hash column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm working with [SearchKick rubygem](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick), and i'm having struggle on search within a Hash column.
Here my example:

```
car:
  {
    parts:
      wheels: {
        rims: ""
      },
      lights: {
        type: ""
      }
  }
```

I need to search in the model Car which ones has lights type "led".

Comment: it might be wizer to (1) post a project related question in the project itself, and (2) include a snippet of the implementation which you are _struggle_ with

Answer (score 0):

I make it work by searching with `Car.search( where: { 'parts.wheels.lights.type' => 'led' } )`.